# How can I search Fields of a Table for a particular value using function in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I know it can be done like this, but I want to do it by using functions.

```
select * from *table_name*
where *column_name* like '%*STR*%';
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it by using functions?

Comment: Because I was told to do so.

Comment: So, create a funtion. what is the probelm?

Comment: By function do you mean Oracle In-Built function or user defined function?

Answer (score 0):

Hi
, You can use **INSTR** function

```
    select * from table_name
    where INSTR(column_name, 'STR') > 0
```

INSTR searches the pattern provided in the function

Comment: That should be `where INSTR(column_name, 'STR') > 0`.

Comment: You can have both the ways, to make him understand, used that method. Any way its good